# Total closed opportunities with different timeframe in single report

Tags: reporting

I would like to produce a report where for each account I have:

- Total opportunities closed
- Total opportunities closed last week
- Total opportunities closed last month

What is the correct approach to get this report? I have considered writing a scheduled job that would compute those numbers every night, is there a better optio?

Comment: you want everything in one report?

Comment: absolutely, is it possible?